# Using Recursion To Print Output

Tags: c++, recursion, turbo-c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    static int i=5;
    clrscr();

    if(--i)
    {
        printf("%d",i);
        main();
    }
    getch();
}
```

When I am running this code, it is not giving any output and when I am removing getch() then after running when I am switching to output screen then it is showing ouput . Why?

I am using Turbo C++.

Comment: First off, you should not be recursing on main(), and create your own function.

Comment: you should flush your standard output or add a newline.

Comment: Then, add `\n` at the end of `printf` function: `printf("%d\n",i);`

Comment: You are **not** free to declare `void main`, it must be `int main`.

Comment: Now press a button 5 times and be amazed...

Comment: why do i need to flush ?Why is it not printing in the current state ?

Comment: Isn't the `clrscr()` deleting the previous output?

Comment: @Jens that depends on which version of the C standard is being used here. Turbo C++ is quite old, isn't it?

Comment: @Codor but the current output should be visible?

Comment: Don't spam tags! C is not C++. (And get a modern toolchain; Turbo-C is **at least** 24 years old!)

Comment: @Ankit you mean the current output from the if, which you're not actually getting into?

Comment: @Gnqz Yes  current output is not visible but if i remove clrscr(
) and getch() then output is visible

Comment: @JeremyP No it doesn't. C89 outright forbids it. And Turbo C is a hosted implementation (not freestanding, where anything goes).

Comment: @Olaf The C tag is legit. It looks like C to me even if he is using the Turbo C++ tool to compile it.

Comment: @Jens Does C89 forbid the implicit `int`. If so, you need to write to Kernighan and Ritchie and tell them TCPL edition 2 is wrong.

Comment: @JeremyP: If compiled as C++, it is not C, no matter "how it looks". Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics.

Comment: @Olaf who says it is being compiled as C++?

Comment: @JeremyP: OP mentions Turbo C**++**. Until further notice we have to assume he is compiling as C++, too.

Comment: `void main()` is an invalid signature for `main` in both languages. The code invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Olaf that's the name of the tool, it can compile C. The use of `printf` and `stdio.h` implies this is C?

Comment: @Olaf Do you know what? I missed the `void`. I withdraw my objection about main'as signature. It is invalid as written in this question.

Comment: why void main() is invalid

Comment: @Ankit Because the C standard says that the only valid signatures are `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char*argv[])` in a "hosted environment", which basically means an environment with an operating system

Comment: @Ankit Most compilers are a bit more relaxed than the standard, which is why you are getting away with it, but `main` is supposed to return an `int` that the OS can check for success or failure.

Comment: @JeremyP thanx buddy

Comment: Why do I have to press key 5 times to come to the coding screen from output screen

Comment: @JeremyP I'd be very careful with such assumptions. After all OP seems not to object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have seen output with debuger if you break on each iteration, but since you are obviously just executing your program what you see is the result of the last `clrscr();`. Since `i` is 0 you're not getting into the if, where the printing happens and you get right at the `getch()`. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: thanx ...this was really helpful

Comment: What you see is the last state of your program, it doesn't mean that there have never been output.

Comment: thanx ... that was helpful....but wanted to know that if i am not using clrscr() the it is printing the output but i hav to press key 5 times to come to the coding screen from output screen . Whay is that so?

Comment: Because once you've reached the last call to main() (when i = 0 and you don't get to call main again) it goes to the next statement, which is the getch(). You press a key, that's the last statement in the function, so it returns to the caller. Then you are right after the if and what's there - another getch(). This happens for each call to main, which is 4 time from the loop + 1 time from the main itself.

Comment: What do u mean?

Comment: Click the tick under the voting count of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `printf` function buffers output internally until either

1. the buffer is full
2. it's asked to print a newline (`\n`)
3. `stdout` is flushed with `fflush()`

You are not doing either of 2 or 3 and the buffer is surely bigger than 5 integers.

You probably want

```
printf("%d\n",i);
```

If you want the ints to be printed without a new line,

```
printf("%d ",i);
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: ok , if i have to just print an integer then printf() prints it.Then it does not wait for buffer to full. Why it is waiting here then?

Comment: Technically I think you're missing a 4th point, 4. at any other point where  ``stdout` feels like it's appropriate. Also, it's not `printf` which buffers, because that would mean that `puts` and `printf` wouldn't mix.

Comment: @Ankrit because you have a `getch()` which is waiting for input.

Comment: @MSalters The buffer belongs to the `FILE*`. `puts` uses the same buffer.

Comment: @Ankit Also move the function that clears the screen to the after the `getch()`